# First launch of Long March-5 using 4 RP-1/LOX boosters. First use of RP-1/LOX LRBs?

Tags: booster, spaceflight-firsts, long-march

The Long March 5's first launch used a LH2/LOX main engine with four RP-1/LOX Liquid Rocket Boosters (LRBs). Is this the first time that RP-1/LOX LRBs have been used in a successful launch to orbit?

[image]

[image]

**above x2:** Screenshots from [the YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jb7qE8pKvU) shown below. Four RP-1/LOX LRBs emit bright white light while LH2/LOX main engine's exhaust is dimmer due to lack of thermal radiation from soot.

[image]

**above:** Long March-5 from [Chinaspacereport](https://chinaspacereport.com/2016/10/29/long-march-5-to-make-debut-flight-in-early-november/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The 4 [Soyuz boosters](http://www.astronautix.com/r/rd-107-8d74.html) are RP1/LOX, this is a design that goes back to the R-7 that launched Sputnik 1. Thousands have been launched.

Liquid boosters are a less common design than solids, but have been produced in greater numbers.

Comment: You should add that the Soyuz booster design is directly derived from the first orbital launcher, the Sputnik R-7.

Comment: Well, technically, Soyuz uses RG-1, but I admit that "RP-1" is commonly used to refer to any kerosene rocket fuel, not just the specific US formulation.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The [Energia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energia) used kerolox strapons.

Comment: Seem's I need to get a good book (or three) on rocket history and sit down and read them!

Comment: Well, Energia is a bit obscure, had a very short operational history, and not talked about much.  Soyuz is the big counterexample.

Comment: Starting point for reading more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_rocket_booster

Comment: @Hobbes I looked there before, the only place LOX/RP-1 is mentioned is the F-1, so I (erroneously is seems) assumed the LRB's mentioned were not LOX/RP-1.

Comment: the article is brief, but contains links to the main articles of each launcher, which contains more detail (although for Soyuz I had to use Google to confirm my memory).